# Blocks calendar drupal 7 next and prev navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, calendar, drupal-7

I have two blocks calendar drupal in the same region.

1. List events.
2. Calendar events

I'm trying to next and previous work with the same month change navigation

```
$( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-1 .date-prev a" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-3 .date-prev a" ).trigger( "click");
});

$( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-1 .date-next a" ).click(function() {
  $( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-3 .date-next a" ).trigger("click");
});
```

but the list of events does not work for me

Thank you very much for your help.

[bloks drupal calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaVXp.png)

Comment: are you using ajax with both the blocks?

Comment: yes,  to avoid overloading page

Comment: hello,  very simple solution.       $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-1 .date-prev a" ).click(function() {

        $( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-3 .date-prev a" ).trigger( "click" );
    });

    $( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-1 .date-next a" ).click(function() {
        $( "#block-views-calendario-academico-block-3 .date-next a" ).trigger("click");
    
    });
});
```